# jQuery fileupload loading and deleting files from database with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jquery plugin [blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and have been working my way through the demo and implementing it into our website. I'm having a few issues though. Basically I'm trying to provide a way of allowing multiple attachments to a webform.

I am submitting the uploads, storing the file location and unique code within a database and getting a successful response, I'm including the unique code within the file object in the response and I see this within the template when and have been able to include it as a text input to confirm that it works.

I want to upload the attachments and then when I click the send button I want to submit the form with the attachment codes.

So the first problem is that I want to be able to delete these files and pass the code so they can be removed from the database at the same time. How can I send this data to the server for each specific button?

Next, when I refresh the page I'm loading all files within the directory, how can I load the list from my database instead, basically what function is loading this list?

And lastly, is there a better built in way of doing this?

Thanks,

Stu

EDIT:

Here is my Custom 'Template Download' Script, the only difference from the demo is that I include a hidden input with the value of the returned unique code. I know this is returning the code and when I change it from a hidden input to a text I can see the code.

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}&code={%=file.unique_code%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="attachs[]" value="{%=file.unique_code%}"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

For my first question I am using a good workaround where by I don't bind the attachment to the webform (queued email) until I submit the whole form. So this problem is solved.

The second problem is still an issue. I'm currently extending the UploadHandler class using `class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {` and have custom `handle_file_upload` and `get_file_objects` functions and a new `get_filenames` function. These are below.

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
        $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );
    // $file->unique_code = 'test';
    $file->unique_code = random_string(32);
    if (empty($file->error)) {
        $email_date = array();
        $email_date['filename'] = $file->name;
        $email_date['size'] = $file->size;
        $email_date['type'] = $file->type;
        $email_date['unique_code'] = $file->unique_code;

        db_insert($this->table, $email_date);
    }
    return $file;
}

protected function get_file_objects($iteration_method = 'get_file_object') {
    if(isset($_POST['email_id'])):
        return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
            array($this, $iteration_method),
            $this->get_filenames($_POST['email_id'])
        )));
    else:
        return array();
    endif;
}

protected function get_filenames($email_id){
    $query = 'SELECT filename FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE eid = '.$email_id;
    $rows = db_array($query);
    $files = array();
    foreach($rows as $row ):
        $files[] = $row['filename'];
    endforeach;
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: "How can I send this data to the server for each specific button?" I assume this is some time later after they've been uploaded, and now you're displaying the list of existing files? Conventional approach would be a separate form wrapping round each button, with the ID included as a parameter (e.g. in a hidden field, perhaps). "how can I load the list from my database instead"...using a SQL query? That's how you get data from a database, I don't really know what else to say!

Comment: I see a lot of words, but no code...

Comment: Sorry, code is now included.